# how to get the data monthly wise in oracle sql between dates

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table of EMPLOYEE , in which I need to show the salary from this month to this month .
Suppose I have dates eg. from date 17/01/2020 and to date 18/02/2020 I need monthly data between these two dates like from 17th JAN to 30th JAN one data and from 1st FEB to 28th FEB.
Please suggest some query i trying it but not able to fetch between two dates.

```
select add_months (to_date(from_date,'dd/mm/yyyy' ), - (level-1)), 'Mon yy') as MONTH,SALARAY from EMPLOYE_BG where CREATED_DATE between TO_DATE('17/01/2020','dd/mm/yyyy')
 and to_date('10/03/2020','dd/mm/yyyy')

O/P:

MONTH    SALARY 
----------------
JAN-20    30000
FEB-20     50000
MAR-20     60000
```

like this  i am expecting the result

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYE_BG 

 SALARY EMPNAME CREATED_DATE
---------------------------------
 30000  JACK   07/01/2020 
 30000  SWETA  08/01/2020  
 30000  RAM    08/01/2020  
 40000  JOHN   01/02/2020
 60000  SIMON  10/03/2020
 70000  KIRA   11/04/2020
```

this is table details

Comment: show us what you try so far

Comment: select SALRAY from EMPLOYE_BG where CREATED_DATE 
between  TO_DATE('17/01/2020','dd/mm/yyyy') and to_date('10/03/2020','dd/mm/yyyy')  , I Tried like this for two dates

Comment: select SALRAY  from EMPLOYE_BG 
WHERE created_date between trunc(to_date('17/01/2020','dd/mm/yyyy'), 'mm')
and to_date('17/01/2020','dd/mm/yyyy') 
this is for single date ,for this its working fine

Comment: Please post your sample data and expected result as text here. Are you facing problems in generating the date range only or for the whole query?

Comment: i am facing the issue for getting the query based on two dates ,as i edited the topic please check the result like that i am expecting from the query from two dates

Comment: @VGK, we need the sample data, not only the expected result. Where are the values coming from ? you say in your question SALES, but I see SALARY.

Comment: hi @RobertoHernandez sorry for inconvenience , i updated the topic